# How to read msg from /odom at time series n and (n-1)

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I hope to compare the message from the consecutive time series n and (n-1) from /odom in python. I am  confused about how to store the msg at time n-1 and time n at the same time, especially for the time sequence t=1.

```
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/odom", Odometry, simple_callback)
    rospy.spin()
def simple_callback():
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    listener()
```

The problem which confused me is that: I was thinking to use some variables to store the msg at sequence n-1 and n like : current_odom=[ ] and last_odom=[ ].  However, I don't how to store the msg at time t=1, because listener() and simple_callback are in loop, I don't know when to pass the data in current_odom=[ ] and last_odom=[ ]. Could you please give me any hints?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315793/how-to-read-msg-from-/odom-at-time-series-n-and-(n-1)/) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2019-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quick and dirty way to do this would be to create a global variable for last and current odom. You could save this variable at the end of every loop. It would look something like this

```
last_odom = Odometry()
current_odom = Odometry()

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/odom", Odometry, simple_callback)
    rospy.spin()

def simple_callback(data):
    global last_odom 
    global current_odom
    last_odom = current_odom
    current_odom = data

if __name__== '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

Originally posted by [humanoid3](https://answers.ros.org/users/38188/humanoid3/) with karma: 26 on 2019-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-16**:
Does `last_odom = Odometry()` mean generate an "object of Odometry" ?

**Comment by [humanoid3](https://answers.ros.org/users/38188/humanoid3/) on 2019-02-16**:
Yes, it will create an empty Odometry type object.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-02-16**:
Instantiate an `Odometry` object

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-16**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-16**:
Learn a new word "Instantiate", thank you!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-17**:
It should be noted that the odometry messages are not time stamped so if you want to know the delta t in seconds you'll also have to record the times the messages are received.

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-17**:
Thank you! They said that I can check something like time in msg.header.stamp to get the msg time